# I would need to split only specific strings to numbers and then maximize these numbers from the specific strings in Google sheets?

Tags: sql, regex, google-sheets, max, array-formulas

Example of my google sheet spreadsheet cells below

---

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA C1 | BBB C4 | AAA C7 |

A1: "AAA C1"
B1: "BBB C4"
C1: "AAA C7"

---

I would need to maximize the highest numbers after the letter "C" from all the strings that start with "AAA". I have only reached to maximize all numbers after "C" by using the formula:

```
=Max(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(a1:c1,"[^[:digit:]]", ""))))
```

Nevertheless, with the above formula I have not been able to select only the strings that start with "AAA". I have tried the function =maxifs, but it does not allow string functions such as MID being applied to the range of cells.

This is my first question here, I hope it is all clear and someone can help me with this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggested Solution #1:**

`=Max(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(A1:C1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AAA",A1:C1))),"[^[:digit:]]", ""))))`

I left your original formula essentially as it was, since you already understand it as it was. All I did was replace your range with a `FILTER` of that range.

The `FILTER` alone — `FILTER(A1:C1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AAA",A1:C1)))` — keeps only those entries in the range where searching for "AAA" results in a position number (i.e., all matches for "AAA" as anything else would result in an error).

If the "AAA" *must* appear first in the string, you can use this version:

`=Max(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(A1:C1,SEARCH("AAA",A1:C1)=1),"[^[:digit:]]", ""))))`

**Suggested Solution #2:**

`=Max(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:C1,"^AAA.+(\d+)$")),-9^9)))`

This will find the max from `REGEXEXTRACT`s matching only the "AAA" cells. If something doesn't match the "AAA" pattern, the `IFERROR` will return an incredibly high negative number (which will rule those out from ever being the `MAX`).

Comment: Happy to help. Please do see the edit I just made (an alternate version of Solution #1 in case your "AAA" MUST be first in the string).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to alter your REGEX expression.

```
^A{3}[^A].*?C(?=\d+)
```

- `^A{3}[^A]` : start with exactly three uppercase `A`
- `.*?C` : find the First uppercase `C`
- `(?=\d+)` : the `C` follow by at least one number.

which will extract the part you want to replace with   empty string.
e.g. `AAA C1` will extract `AAA C` which after replace will leave you only `1`.

Comment: Many thanks! How would you notate the part: ^A{3}[^A] of the REGEX function if the first three letters where ABC?

Also, where would you put the complete expression ^A{3}[^A].*?C(?=\d+)? As if I am inputting it in the following way: =Max(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(a1:c1,"^A{3}[^A].*?C(?=\d+)?", "")))) it gives me an error.

Comment: if you want string start with `ABC` you can replace the whole `^A{3}[^A]` with `^ABC`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=MAX(INDEX(1*IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:C1; "^AAA.+(\d+)"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mention:

> *...maximize the highest numbers after the letter "C" from all the strings that start with "AAA".*

The mentioned answers work for a single row.
If you want to apply it to **any range of rows in more complex situations** you can use

```
=MAX(INDEX(IFERROR( 
   REGEXEXTRACT(FLATTEN(A1:C),"^AAA .*C(\d+)")+0)))
```

[image]